# only one of 4 picture boxes appear and picture appears in 100*55 rectangle

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on a project, but I face a problem. I cannot find the solution, maybe you can help me.

Below you can see the details of my code:

```
private void InitializeComponent()
    {
      this.BKezdes = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
      this.PPalya = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
      this.LPalyaMerete = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
      this.CBPalyaMerete = new System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox();
      this.PKezelo = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
      this.PKezelo.SuspendLayout();
      this.SuspendLayout();
      //
      // BKezdes
      //
      this.BKezdes.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(1133, 247);
       this.BKezdes.Name = "BKezdes";
      this.BKezdes.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(208, 64);
      this.BKezdes.TabIndex = 0;
      this.BKezdes.Text = "Kezdés";
      this.BKezdes.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
      this.BKezdes.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.BKezdes_Click);
      //
      // PPalya
      //
      this.PPalya.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
      this.PPalya.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 12);
       this.PPalya.Name = "PPalya";
      this.PPalya.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(773, 651);
      this.PPalya.TabIndex = 1;
      //
      // PKezelo
      //
      this.PKezelo.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
      this.PKezelo.Controls.Add(this.CBPalyaMerete);
      this.PKezelo.Controls.Add(this.LPalyaMerete);
      this.PKezelo.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(784, 12);
       this.PKezelo.Name = "PKezelo";
      this.PKezelo.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(218, 651);
      this.PKezelo.TabIndex = 2;
      //
      // Fkepernyo
      //
      this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
      this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
      this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(1461, 757);
      this.Controls.Add(this.BKezdes);
      this.Controls.Add(this.PKezelo);
      this.Controls.Add(this.PPalya);
      this.Name = "Fkepernyo";
      this.Text = "Amolba";
      this.PKezelo.ResumeLayout(false);
      this.PKezelo.PerformLayout();
      this.ResumeLayout(false);
    }
public partial class Fkepernyo : Form
  {
    Mezo m;
    List<Mezo> mezok;
    public Fkepernyo()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void BKezdes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      mezok = new List<Mezo>();
      int xKezdes = 1;
      int yKezdes;
      int width = 20;
      int height = 20;
      //MessageBox.Show(PPalya.Width + " " + PPalya.Height);
      for (int i = 0; i <2; i++)
      {
        yKezdes = 1;
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        {
          m = new Mezo(xKezdes, yKezdes, width, height, 1);
          PPalya.Controls.Add(m);
          mezok.Add(m);
          //MessageBox.Show(""+m.Location);
          //MessageBox.Show(i + " " + j);
          yKezdes += width;
        }
        xKezdes += height;
      }
      /*foreach (var item in mezok)
    {
        PPalya.Controls.Add(item);
    }*/
    }
    void PBPalyaElemek_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
      if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        MessageBox.Show("Left button clicked");
    }
    private void CBPalyaMerete_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }0
  }
public Mezo(int x, int y, int width, int height,int kep)
    {
      PictureBox PBPalyaElemek;
      PBPalyaElemek = new PictureBox();
      PBPalyaElemek.Width = width;
      PBPalyaElemek.Height = height;
      var redX = new Bitmap(rings_and_x_s.Properties.Resources.red_x);
      var greenCircle = new Bitmap(rings_and_x_s.Properties.Resources.green_circle);
      if (kep == 1)
      {
        PBPalyaElemek.Image = greenCircle;
      }
      else
      {
        PBPalyaElemek.Image = redX;
      }
      PBPalyaElemek.Location = new Point(x, y);
      PBPalyaElemek.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
      PBPalyaElemek.MouseClick += PBPalyaElemek_MouseClick;
      PBPalyaElemek.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
      Controls.Add(PBPalyaElemek);
    }
```

There are two problems:

1. When I try to display the images on the screen, it only appears in 100 * 55 rectangles.
2. When I give the instruction to generate 4 picture boxes, the first one appears and the others do not.

I would appreciate any idea which help me to find a solution.

Comment: Try removing `Controls.Add(PBPalyaElemek)`. that's not needed.

Comment: What is Mezo derived from? Seems to be a ContainerControl. Where do you set the position of the Mezo instances added to PPalya.Controls?

Comment: if I remove Controls.Add(PBPalyaElemek), the picture box will not appear

Comment: yes i made a mistake. class Mezo : PictureBox.

Comment: I think that is how I set the position: PBPalyaElemek.Location = new Point(x, y);

Answer (score 0):

```
 public Mezo(int x, int y, int width, int height, int kep)
        {
            X = x;
            Y = y;
            OWidth = width;
            OHeight = height;
            Kep = kep;
        }

        public int X { get; set; }
        public int Y { get; set; }
        public int OWidth { get; set; }
        public int OHeight { get; set; }
        public int Kep { get; set; }


        public PictureBox Keszit()
        {
            PictureBox PBPalyaElemek;
            PBPalyaElemek = new PictureBox();
            PBPalyaElemek.Width = this.OWidth;
            PBPalyaElemek.Height = this.OHeight;
            var redX = new Bitmap(rings_and_x_s.Properties.Resources.red_x);
            var greenCircle = new Bitmap(rings_and_x_s.Properties.Resources.green_circle);
            if (this.Kep == 1)
            {
                PBPalyaElemek.Image = greenCircle;
            }
            else
            {
                PBPalyaElemek.Image = redX;
            }
            PBPalyaElemek.Location = new Point(this.X, this.Y);
            PBPalyaElemek.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
            PBPalyaElemek.MouseClick += PBPalyaElemek_MouseClick;
            PBPalyaElemek.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
            Controls.Add(PBPalyaElemek);

            return PBPalyaElemek;

        }

        public MouseEventHandler PBPalyaElemek_MouseClick { get; }

Mezo m;
        List<PictureBox> pbk;
        public Fkepernyo()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void BKezdes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pbk = new List<PictureBox>();
            int meret = CBPalyaMerete.SelectedIndex+3;
            int xKezdes = 6;
            int yKezdes;
            int width = 20;
            int height = 20;
            //MessageBox.Show(PPalya.Width + " " + PPalya.Height);
            for (int i = 0; i <20; i++)
            {
                yKezdes = 6;
                for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
                {
                    m = new Mezo(xKezdes, yKezdes, width, height, 1);
                    PPalya.Controls.Add(m.Keszit());
                    pbk.Add(m.Keszit());
                    //MessageBox.Show(""+m.Location);
                    //MessageBox.Show(i + " " + j);
                    yKezdes += width;
                }
                xKezdes += height;
            }



            foreach (var item in pbk)
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"{item.Location.X} {item.Location.Y}");
                //PPalya.Controls.Add(item);
            }
            BKezdes.Visible = false;
        }
```

thx for dani he is foud the soltion.

Comment: What exactly was the solution?  If you are going to post this as an answer, don't just paste a hundred lines of working code.  Describe what had to be changed and why that change resolved the issue.

Comment: had to create a method that gets the picture box as the return value, and so the data was saved